# Windows application error after install

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the following error after install my windows application to client machine.
But it works properly in my development machine.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The clue is in the error message...  you're missing a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Office Interop assemblies on the target machine. They're available for download as a redistributable from the link below

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508